# C++ reserved word as function pointer name in C struct

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, reserved-words

I suspect I know the answer to this already, but am curious if any experts out there have any tricks.

I have a C library built with the intention of being a C framework (unsafe functions unused, similar naming convention cross-platform, etc.). This works fine, up until I try to use it within a C++ project, where the C 'namespaced' function name conflicts with a C++ reserved word, in this case `delete`.

Here's the 'file' namespace, where I want it delete to be one of the function names:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(__linux__) || defined(BSD)
#   include <fcntl.h>
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
#   if defined(_MSC_VER)
#       pragma warning ( push )
        // Disable: default constructor could not be generated
#       pragma warning ( disable : 4510 )
        // Disable: assignment operator could not be generated
#       pragma warning ( disable : 4512 )
        // Disable: struct <unnamed-tag> can never be instantiated
#       pragma warning ( disable : 4610 )
#   endif
extern "C" {
#endif



typedef struct
{
    int(*const close)(FILE* fp);
    int(*const copy)(const char* src, const char* dest);
    int(*const delete)(const char* path);
    int(*const flush)(FILE* fp);
    long(*const get_file_size)(FILE* fp);
    long(*const get_size)(const char* path);
    FILE*(*const open)(const char* name, const char* modes);
    int(*const path_exists)(const char* path);
    size_t(*const read)(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE* stream);
    size_t(*const write)(const void* ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE* stream);

} namespace_file;

extern namespace_file const file;



#if defined(__cplusplus)
}   // extern "C"
#   if defined(_MSC_VER)
#       pragma warning ( pop )
#   endif
#endif
```

Now I'm writing some tests using gtest, and encounter the reserved word issue - is there anyway to bypass this, or shall I simply rename the function to `purge` or similar?

```
TEST(cfwkFile, fDelete)
{
    // all three of these error as 'delete' is reserved
    EXPECT_EQ(0, file.delete(CFWK_TEST_FAIL_FILE));
    EXPECT_EQ(1, file.delete(CFWK_TEST_PASS_FILE));
    EXPECT_EQ(1, file.delete(CFWK_TEST_PASS_FILE_COPY));
}
```

Comment: You can't use C++ reserved words as identifiers in your C code if you intend to feed them to a C++ compiler.

Comment: Why not just `#define delete` to something else before including the header and `#undef delete` afterwards?

Comment: @R.. That's probably a very bad idea! Even with the `#undef`.

Comment: @R.. Technically you can't `#define` a keyword.  Most compilers support it as an extension though.

Comment: @TavianBarnes, You legally can if not using the standard library. Unfortunately, with third party headers, it might sometimes end up being the best option under the circumstances.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: If it's your own code and you intend to use it as a C++-accessible interface, then yes, I would agree. But if it's a third-party C library and you're using it as foreign-language code from C++, that might be the simplest solution.

Comment: I'm trying to make this as standard as possible, since my intention is for others to be using it; defining keywords may not end too well, especially since a rename would just be a lot safer!

Comment: @R.. From N3242, §17.6.4.3.1, p. 2: "A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords".  Admittedly there seems to be some disagreement over what "keyword" means in that context but I always took it  to mean that `#define delete` is illegal.

Comment: @R.. Oh never mind, §17.6.4 "describes restrictions on C++ programs that use the facilities of the C++ standard library", so you're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"is there anyway to bypass this, or shall I simply rename the function to purge or similar?"*
>
> ```
>   int(*const delete)(const char* path);
>           // ^^^^^^
> ```

Yes you should rename it, if the code in question is under your control!
You simply can't use a function pointer named `delete` in C++ compiled code, because it's a reserved keyword for the language.

You just need to make it different from the keyword. Instead of renaming it to `purge`, which might be misleading from a semantic level, you can still use something like

```
int(*const delete_)(const char* path);
              // ^
```

to get it distinct from the C++ keyword.

---

About your comments mentioning kind of *asymetric*/*inconsistent naming*:
Just use a `_` postfix for all of them. As giving an opiniion, that's my preferred style for member variables of structs or classes anyway.

Comment: Yeah, was wondering if anyone had any magic tricks to get round it, but wasn't getting my hopes up! Just wanted an 'expected' function name, 'delete' a file is significantly more common that 'purge' - hey ho!

Comment: @ZXcvbnM You can still use something like `delete_` to come over these semantic level concerns.

Comment: Good point, hadn't considered that; may look just a little more peculiar than the others, but that ticks all the checkboxes for expectations. Think I'll do that..

Comment: what about `remove` ?

Comment: Or `delet` as homage to [`creat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/what-did-ken-thompson-mean-when-he-said-id-spell-create-with-an-e?rq=1). :3

Comment: lol :P Might just be me, but `remove`/`unlink` just isn't as clear to the final result in comparison to `delete`...

Comment: @ZXcvbnM _"... may look just a little more peculiar than the others ..."_ Just use a `_` postfix for all of them. That's my preferred style for any member variables of structs or classes anyway.

Comment: An idea, but I'd rather make it the exception than the rule - I'm careful enough for naming schemes for everything else, it's just purely the semantics of this individual case :)